# 99 Problems number 9 in Clojure (Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists)

Tags: clojure, lisp

this is handling the nieve case of a single list with duplicate elements, I was getting into a knot handling some nested lists, so I wanted to write the simple case first. 
 so I have:

```
    (defn packDuplicatesIntoLists [listOfElements l e]
      (if(= e 'nil)
        'true
        (if(= () listOfElements)
          (if 
            (= e '())
            l
            (list l e)
          )
          (if 
              (= (first listOfElements) (first e) )
              (packDuplicatesIntoLists (rest listOfElements) l (cons (first listOfElements) e))
      (packDuplicatesIntoLists (rest listOfElements) (list l e) (first listOfElements))
          )
        )
```

)
)

```
    (packDuplicatesIntoLists '(2) '(1 1) '(2 2))  (packDuplicatesIntoLists '() '(1 1) '(2 2))  (packDuplicatesIntoLists '() '() '()) (packDuplicatesIntoLists '(1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4) '() '())
```

BUT the
          (packDuplicatesIntoLists (rest listOfElements) (list l e) (first listOfElements))
is getting me into trouble,

```
    #'NintyNineProblems.LearnSpace/packDuplicatesIntoLists
    ((1 1) (2 2 2))
    ((1 1) (2 2))
    ()
    IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505
```

whats wrong with that line?

Comment: oh, oops, that lise should have been:          (packDuplicatesIntoLists (rest listOfElements) (list l e) (list (first listOfElements))), the third arg is assumed to be a list

Comment: so it works never mind :}

Comment: (defn packDuplicatesIntoLists [listOfElements l e]
        (if(= '() listOfElements)
         (if 
           (= e '())
           l
           (cons e l)
         )
        (if 
             (= (first listOfElements) (first e) )
             (packDuplicatesIntoLists (rest listOfElements) l (cons (first listOfElements) e))
             (packDuplicatesIntoLists (rest listOfElements) (cons e l) (list (first listOfElements)))
         )
            )
      )
    
        (packDuplicatesIntoLists '(2 2 2 4 4 4 5 5 5 8 8 8 6 9 9 9) '() '())  
((9 9 9) (6) (8 8 8) (5 5 5) (4 4 4) (2 2 2) s())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, it still reverses the lsit, but tail recursive

```
     (defn packDuplicatesIntoLists [listOfElements l e]
      (if(= '() listOfElements)
       (cons e l)
       (if 
        (= (first listOfElements) (first e) )
         (recur (rest listOfElements) l (cons (first listOfElements) e))
         (if (= '() e)
          (recur (rest listOfElements) l (list (first listOfElements)))
          (recur (rest listOfElements) (cons e l) (list (first listOfElements)))
         )
        )
       )
      )
```

(packDuplicatesIntoLists '(2 2 2 4 4 4 5 5 5 8 8 8 6 9 9 9 9 9) '() '()) 
(packDuplicatesIntoLists '() '() '()) (packDuplicatesIntoLists 'nil '() '())